# Running django project failing after upgrade to django 3.2.18

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I upgraded my django project from django 3.0.6 to django 3.2.18. After that I cannot run my project with following command:
`python -m my_project.manage run server 127.0.0.1:8000`
it produces below error message:
`python.exe: No module named my_project.__main__; 'my_project' is a package and cannot be directly executed`
However when I run:
`python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000`
It works perfectly fine. Does anyone have similar issue?

I suspected it was related to django app configuration but changes in this field does not help.

Comment: is your package in form of pypi package ? maybe just do `python my_project.manage run server 127.0.0.1:8000`

Comment: It does not help :/